# Import symmetric key in java keystore with command line

Tags: java, encryption, keystore, keytool

It is possible to use the command line to import a symmetric key into a java keystore? I have found how to import a public/private key pair, and how to generate a symmetric key, but if I already have a symmetric key, can I store it into the keystore?

Comment: Here is an article that complains about this feature missing, and presents a solution involving some custom code: http://java.dzone.com/articles/secret-key-import-java

Comment: Same question on Superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/766504/how-do-i-import-a-raw-aes-key-to-a-jceks-keystore (answer there also "nope")